# Destroying a permanent with ability "as long as this card is on the battlefield"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Example scenario is:

1. P1 plays a creature like Skilled Animator that says:

> When Skilled Animator enters the battlefield, target artifact you control becomes an artifact creature with base power and toughness 5/5 for as long as Skilled Animator remains on the battlefield.

2. P1 has an artifact, so it becomes a creature with base power and toughness 5/5
3. P1 goes to attack with at least the artifact
4. P2 plays an instant card that deals enough damage to the Skilled Animator to kill him. But the artifact creature is not blocked

What happens to the artifact/creature? Does it still deal combat damage, or does the instant resolve first, killing Skilled Animator, and causing the artifact to lose its creature status before dealing damage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Provided that Player 2 sequences correctly, the artifact will cease being a creature before combat damage is dealt.**

The situation that you're describing would play out like this:

1. Player 1 declares attackers, including the artifact creature.
2. After attackers are declared, both players will receive priority. Player 2 can use their instant now to kill the Skilled Animator. At this point, the artifact is no longer a creature. This will cause it to be removed from combat, per rule 506.4 (emphasis mine):

> A permanent is removed from combat if it leaves the battlefield, if its controller changes, if it phases out, if an effect specifically removes it from combat, if it’s a planeswalker that’s being attacked and stops being a planeswalker, or if it’s an attacking or blocking creature that regenerates (see rule 701.12) **or stops being a creature**. A creature that’s removed from combat stops being an attacking, blocking, blocked, and/or unblocked creature. A planeswalker that’s removed from combat stops being attacked.

3. The declare blockers step begins. After Player 2 declares their blockers (if any), both players will receive priority again. At this point, Player 2 can use their instant again, with the same effect.
4. The combat damage step begins, and damage is dealt. *After* damage is dealt, both players will receive priority again. At this point, Player 2 can use their instant; however, at this point, it's too late to prevent the damage, as it has already been dealt.

Comment: Just want to expand on my edit comment: Combat damage happens before any player gets priority in the combat damage step. If you haven't already removed the creature by then, it's too late. *"510.2 Second, all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously. [...] 510.3 Third, the active player gets priority."*

Comment: @Rainbolt You're absolutely right, I had the combat damage step backwards in my head. Sorry about that!